# Put it back wherever you found it

Tags: free-relative-clauses

> Put it back wherever you found it. [fused relative]
>   (CGEL,p.764)

The book says the sentence means “*Put it back in the place where you found it*.” But this seems to be insufficient to deliver the meaning, I suspect. And this is what I think to alter the account: *Put it back in the place, wherever it is, that [or where] you found it*.
Am I misreading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that “put it back in the place where you found it” is more than sufficient, in fact "in the place" is completely unnecessary; it would come across as overly specific. "Put it back where you found it" would be a normal thing so say, but still "where you found it" can be somewhat unnecessary in many situations because it is implied that you found it somewhere, leaving us with "put it back."

Comment: Sometimes the addition of *Wherever you found it" is used to head-off the rebuttal, "But i found it clear across town and I don't want to go all the way back there."  the *wherever your found it" says, "I don't care how hard it is to put it back where you found it, you need to do what it takes to put it back there- no matter where that is."

Comment: Spoken like a true dad, @Jim, although I've no idea if you are. :)